# Display respective text box when checkbox is checked in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Display respective text box  when checkbox is checked in the table which is inside the form.
The rows will generate dynamically depending upon the data send from the server, along with the data.
When the checkbox is checked the text box of that row should be displayed otherwise it should be hidden

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="available-products-table">
    <table class="table">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S.no</th>
                  <th>Product Name</th>
                  <th>Quanity</th>
                  <th>Brand</th>
                  <th>Color</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Quanity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary/"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </fieldset>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What you have tried till now and what sort of problem you are getting ? No one is going to give your ready made code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
$(".table input[name='product-status']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find("input[name='send-quality']").show();
    }
    else{
      $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find("input[name='send-quality']").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
input[name='send-quality']
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="available-products-table">
    <table class="table">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S.no</th>
                  <th>Product Name</th>
                  <th>Quanity</th>
                  <th>Brand</th>
                  <th>Color</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Quanity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shoes</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>Black</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-quality" id="send-quality"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </fieldset>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(this).is(":checked")`, see if the checkbox is checked. If it is checked, show the relevant input box. I have added a class `hidden` to each input box for this demo:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    $(this).parents("tr:first").find('.hidden').show();
  else
    $(this).parents("tr:first").find('.hidden').hide();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form class="available-products-table">
    <table class="table">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Quanity</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Quanity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>adidas</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class='hidden' name="send-quality" id="send-quality" /> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>adidas</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class='hidden' name="send-quality" id="send-quality"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>adidas</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class='hidden' name="send-quality" id="send-quality"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </fieldset>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```